# onnxruntime inference is way slower than pytorch on GPU

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, onnx, onnxruntime

I was comparing the inference times for an input using pytorch and onnxruntime and I find that onnxruntime is actually slower on GPU while being significantly faster on CPU

I was tryng this on  Windows 10.

- ONNX Runtime installed from source - ONNX Runtime version: 1.11.0 (onnx version 1.10.1)
- Python version - 3.8.12
- CUDA/cuDNN version - cuda version 11.5, cudnn version 8.2
- GPU model and memory - Quadro M2000M, 4 GB

**Relevant code -**

```
import torch
from torchvision import models
import onnxruntime    # to inference ONNX models, we use the ONNX Runtime
import onnx
import os
import time

batch_size = 1
total_samples = 1000
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    
def convert_to_onnx(resnet):
   resnet.eval()
   dummy_input = (torch.randn(batch_size, 3, 224, 224, device=device)).to(device=device)
   input_names = [ 'input' ]
   output_names = [ 'output' ]
   torch.onnx.export(resnet, 
               dummy_input,
               "resnet18.onnx",
               verbose=True,
               opset_version=13,
               input_names=input_names,
               output_names=output_names,
               export_params=True,
               do_constant_folding=True,
               dynamic_axes={
                  'input': {0: 'batch_size'},  # variable length axes
                  'output': {0: 'batch_size'}}        
               )
                  
def infer_pytorch(resnet):
   print('Pytorch Inference')
   print('==========================')
   print()

   x = torch.randn((batch_size, 3, 224, 224))
   x = x.to(device=device)

   latency = []
   for i in range(total_samples):
      t0 = time.time()
      resnet.eval()
      with torch.no_grad():
         out = resnet(x)
      latency.append(time.time() - t0)

   print('Number of runs:', len(latency))
   print("Average PyTorch {} Inference time = {} ms".format(device.type, format(sum(latency) * 1000 / len(latency), '.2f')))  

def to_numpy(tensor):
   return tensor.detach().cpu().numpy() if tensor.requires_grad else tensor.cpu().numpy()

def infer_onnxruntime():
   print('Onnxruntime Inference')
   print('==========================')
   print()

   onnx_model = onnx.load("resnet18.onnx")
   onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)

   # Input
   x = torch.randn((batch_size, 3, 224, 224))
   x = x.to(device=device)
   x = to_numpy(x)

   so = onnxruntime.SessionOptions()
   so.execution_mode = onnxruntime.ExecutionMode.ORT_SEQUENTIAL
   so.graph_optimization_level = onnxruntime.GraphOptimizationLevel.ORT_ENABLE_ALL
   
   exproviders = ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']

   model_onnx_path = os.path.join(".", "resnet18.onnx")
   ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model_onnx_path, so, providers=exproviders)

   options = ort_session.get_provider_options()
   cuda_options = options['CUDAExecutionProvider']
   cuda_options['cudnn_conv_use_max_workspace'] = '1'
   ort_session.set_providers(['CUDAExecutionProvider'], [cuda_options])

   #IOBinding
   input_names = ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name
   output_names = ort_session.get_outputs()[0].name
   io_binding = ort_session.io_binding()

   io_binding.bind_cpu_input(input_names, x)
   io_binding.bind_output(output_names, device)
   
   #warm up run
   ort_session.run_with_iobinding(io_binding)
   ort_outs = io_binding.copy_outputs_to_cpu()

   latency = []

   for i in range(total_samples):
      t0 = time.time()
      ort_session.run_with_iobinding(io_binding)
      latency.append(time.time() - t0)
      ort_outs = io_binding.copy_outputs_to_cpu()
   print('Number of runs:', len(latency))
   print("Average onnxruntime {} Inference time = {} ms".format(device.type, format(sum(latency) * 1000 / len(latency), '.2f')))   

if __name__ == '__main__':
   torch.cuda.empty_cache()
   resnet = (models.resnet18(pretrained=True)).to(device=device)
   convert_to_onnx(resnet)
   infer_onnxruntime()
   infer_pytorch(resnet)
```

**Output**

If run on CPU,

```
Average onnxruntime cpu Inference time = 18.48 ms
Average PyTorch cpu Inference time = 51.74 ms
```

but, if run on GPU, I see

```
Average onnxruntime cuda Inference time = 47.89 ms
Average PyTorch cuda Inference time = 8.94 ms
```

If I change graph optimizations to onnxruntime.GraphOptimizationLevel.ORT_DISABLE_ALL, I see some improvements in inference time on GPU, but its still slower than Pytorch.

I use io binding for the input tensor numpy array and the nodes of the model are on GPU.

Further, during the processing for onnxruntime, I print device usage stats and I see this -

```
Using device: cuda:0
GPU Device name: Quadro M2000M
Memory Usage:
Allocated: 0.1 GB
Cached:    0.1 GB
```

So, GPU device is being used.

Further, I have used the resnet18.onnx model from the ModelZoo to see if it is a converted mode issue, but i get the same results.

What am I doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: You should not use `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` as it  it will slow down your code for no gain  https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-torch-cuda-empty-cache-do-and-where-should-i-add-it/40975

Answer (score 1):

When calculating inference time exclude all code that should be run once like `resnet.eval()` from the loop.

Please include imports in example

```
import torch
from torchvision import models
import onnxruntime    # to inference ONNX models, we use the ONNX Runtime
import onnx
import os
import time
```

After running your example GPU only I found that time differs only ~x2, so the speed difference may be caused by framework characteristics. For more details explore [onnx conversion optimization](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/2796)

```
Onnxruntime Inference
==========================

Number of runs: 1000
Average onnxruntime cuda Inference time = 4.76 ms
Pytorch Inference
==========================

Number of runs: 1000
Average PyTorch cuda Inference time = 2.27 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: 1) I have included the imports now, sorry about missing that earlier
2) The resnet.eval(), would anyway affect only pytorch inference time, and since in case of GPU inference the pytorch is already faster, excluding this won't explain why onnxruntime is slower
3) For your inference, did you run it on Windows 10 or linux? So if you disable the optimization for onnx, with ```so.graph_optimization_level = onnxruntime.GraphOptimizationLevel.ORT_ENABLE_ALL```, do you actually see that onnxruntime is faster?

Comment: Regarding the link you shared, I had gone through it earlier itself and tried most of the suggestions there, but was not seeing much change. But seeing a better performance on your machine for the same code means maybe something is wrong in my setup

Answer (score 0):

for CPU you don't need to use `io-binding`, it is required only for GPU.
and don't change session options as onnxruntime by default selects the best options.

the following things may help to speed up the gpu

1. make sure to install `onnxruntime-gpu` which comes with prebuilt `CUDA EP` and `TensortRT EP`.
2. you are currently binding the inputs and outputs to the CPU. when using onnxruntime with CUDA EP you should bind them to GPU (to avoid copying inputs/output btw CPU and GPU) refer [here](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/app/onnxruntime/helpsphinx/api_summary.html#id4)

I suggest you use `io_binding.bind_input()` method instead of `io_binding.bind_cpu_input()`

```
   for i in range(total_samples):
      t0 = time.time()
      ort_session.run_with_iobinding(io_binding)
      latency.append(time.time() - t0)
   -> ort_outs = io_binding.copy_outputs_to_cpu()
```

copying output every time from GPU to CPU for 1000 times drops the performance.

Comment: 1) I am using onnxruntime-gpu since I have built it from source along with the CUDA execution provider
2) I had referred that before, but as 'Scenario 1' states there - 'A graph is executed on a device other than CPU, for instance CUDA. Users can use IOBinding to put input on CUDA as the follows' and the example has ```io_binding.bind_cpu_input('input', X)``` for this Scenario, I did it that way since for GPU i want to move it to GPU from CPU.

Comment: Anyway, I also tried as you suggested by changing the code as -
```data = onnxruntime.OrtValue.ortvalue_from_numpy(x, device.type, 0)
   io_binding.bind_input(input_names, device, 0, np.float32, [batch_size, 3, 224, 224], data.data_ptr())```
but the inference time for onnxruntime is pretty much the same (around 48 ms and way slower than pytorch)

3) For copying outputs part, I am not including that time for performance measurement